# Entity Framework (database-first) - re-generating code

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

Is there a convenient way to re-generate entity classes in Visual Studio? My project is under version control and I don't want to add the auto-generated .cs files to repository. When I clone the repository to new location, I have to open the .edmx file, make a dummy change (move entity couple of pixels, change zoom value etc.) and save for the code to generate. It seems silly and I was wondering if there is a way I could trigger generating the code (so I can automatize it later on). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is a button for this in Visual Studio menu: Build -> Transform All T4 Templates.